# How do I get templated values in uri tag for http-client-requests metrics using Spring-Boot's RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

We are using Spring Boot 2.1.4 and the `micrometer-registry-prometheus` dependency to capture metrics.

We have a case where a Spring Boot service uses a RestTemplate to call out to another service. The metrics being generated by this call contain the actual values in the URI instead of the templated values.

For example, in the `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint, I see entries like this:

`http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="someClient",method="GET",status="200",uri="/person/lookup?firstName=Tony&lastName=Soprano",} 1.0`

Based on the documentation, I would expect to see the variable names rather than the values, like this:

`http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="someClient",method="GET",status="200",uri="/person/lookup?firstName={firstName}&lastName={lastName}",} 1.0`

Is there a way to get the default `http.client.requests` metric values to use the templated values for the URI tag?

The Spring documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-http-clients says this about the uri tag:

> Request’s URI template prior to variable substitution, if possible (for example, /api/person/{id})

How do we make it possible for the variable substitution to take place?

Comment: AFAIK, it is intended to have separate log for each call with used values. But, monitoring tools such as Grafana helps to show the results in generic way. IMHO, if it is logged without values, it'll be difficult to figure out the metric results.

Comment: @RaufAgayev if we are calling {id} 1000 times, effectively it creates 1000 entries for metrics  and results in performance issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you are using the `RestTemplateBuilder` to build your `RestTemplate` as otherwise you wouldn't be getting the metrics registered.

Are you actually passing a templated url into `RestTemplate`s exchange methods and pass along the params for subsbitution? Works-for-me on `2.1.4.RELEASE` and `2.2.1.RELEASE`.

```
    template.getForObject("http://localhost:" + this.serverPort + "/hello/{id}",
            String.class, Collections.singletonMap("id", "loop"));
```

Results in:

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{application="micrometered2",clientName="localhost",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/hello/{id}",} 23.0
```