# Improperly tagged metrics when using Swagger/OpenAPI codegen with a RestTemplate

Tags: java, resttemplate, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen, spring-micrometer

My team generates some Java code using `RestTemplate`s from an OpenAPI spec using the maven plugins for this. We have used both the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` and `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` which both seem to generate approximately the same code.

When it comes to collecting metrics from these `RestTemplate`s using Micrometer, I find that the URIs aren't templated in the tags. For example, with a REST endpoint like `/customers/{cid}`, I'd want the Micrometer metric to be tagged with `uri=/customers/{cid}`. However, instead we find that the metric is tagged with `uri=/customers/customer1`, `uri=/customers/customer2`, etc. This effectively makes this tag useless for us.

Note from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942924/how-do-i-get-templated-values-in-uri-tag-for-http-client-requests-metrics-using) that if the `RestTemplate` is allowed to do the templating itself, then the metric will be tagged in the way I want.

However, the generated code always looks like this:

```java
String path = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/customers/{cid}").buildAndExpand(uriVariables).toUriString();
```

ie, the templating is done *before* the `RestTemplate`, and thus the metrics are tagged with the fully fleshed out URI.

Our configuration for the plugins looks like this. When using the openapi-generator version it also looks similar. I've tried playing around with a few of the configuration parameters to no avail.

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/my-spec.yml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <configOptions>
                                <useOptional>true</useOptional>
                                <modelPackage>${my.groupId}.model</modelPackage>
                                <apiPackage>${my.groupId}.api</apiPackage>
                                <invokerPackage>${my.groupId}</invokerPackage>
                                <groupId>${my.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>api</artifactId>
                                <fullJavaUtil>false</fullJavaUtil>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <dateLibrary>java8-instant</dateLibrary>
                            </configOptions>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I've looked into the configuration properties for both the swagger-codegen plugin and the openapi-generator plugin and haven't found anything that seems to help with this. Does anyone know of a way to fix/improve this behaviour?

EDIT: After looking into it a bit more, the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` version of the code does seem to do something that I'd expect to use the `RestTemplate` for url templating. However in the `RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider` the `urlTemplate` is still coming through as `null`.